# React Native on Mac OSX Maverics VM

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am making a native app for iOS for the first time. I have windows in my PC.
So, I setup a virtual MAC environment in Oracle Virtual Box. I installed Honewbrew, node and React Native Command Line Tools.
Then I created a New Project by react-native init.
After that, when I ran command "react-native run-ios". I got this error:

xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH
/Users/nerizen/MyProject/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list devices
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "simctl", not a developer tool or in PATH

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:486:13)
at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:506:13)
at _runIOS (runIOS.js:62:19)
at runIOS.js:24:5
```

So, I thought , maybe xcode is missing. So, I tried installing XCode.
But, I am getting this error :
Xcode can’t be installed on “Untitled” because OS X version 10.11 or later is required.
I have OSX 10.9 VM. 
What should I do in this scenerio ?

Comment: You need an older version of Xcode, on that supports 10.9 or you will need to update your OS X version. But be aware that running OS X in a virtual machine on none Apple hardware is not allowed by the OS X user license,

Comment: So, I cannot release my iOS app using MAc Virtual Machine ??

Comment: That is not what I said, But the user license of OS X does not allow you to run OS X on other hardware then Apple.